# C, pointers and void functions

Tags: c++, c, pointers, char-pointer

Have looked for a similar answer but nothing I try works.
Have an issue, I want to change the value of `word` by calling the void function `init()` but when I print the word it does not work.

Have spent way to many hours on this so any help would be appreciated.

```
int main(void)
{
   char word[MAX_WORD_LEN + 1];
   unsigned wrongGuesses = 0;
   int guessedLetters[ALPHABET_SIZE] = {
   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
   };
   init(&word);
   printf("%s", word);
   displayWord(word, guessedLetters);
   guessLetter(word, guessedLetters);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void init(char* word)
{
    int randValue;
    char* randWord;
    const char* words[NUM_WORDS] = {
      "array",      "auto",       "break",      "case",       "cast",
      "character",  "comment",    "compiler",   "constant",   "continue",
      "default",    "double",     "dynamic",    "else",       "enum",
      "expression", "extern",     "file",       "float",      "function",
      "goto",       "heap",       "identifier", "library",    "linker",
      "long",       "macro",      "operand",    "operator",   "pointer",
      "prototype",  "recursion",  "register",   "return",     "short",
      "signed",     "sizeof",     "stack",      "statement",  "static",
      "string",     "struct",     "switch",     "typedef",    "union",
     "unsigned",   "variable",   "void",       "volatile",   "while"
    };
    int seed;
    seed = (time(NULL));
    srand(seed);
    randValue = rand() % NUM_WORDS;
    randWord = words[randValue];
    printf("%s", randWord);
    *word = randWord;
}
```

Comment: Your main should have the following signature: `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`. Especially for C++ (which you've tagged this question as, so I assume there's a reason for that).

Comment: Aside from the problem you have, this variation of the table of words makes it far easier to survive wayward maintenance without breaking anything:  `const char *words[] = {"array", "auto",`  ...`, "while"}; #define NUM_WORDS  (sizeof (words)/sizeof (words[0]))`

Comment: `word` already of type `char*` so you don't need to pass it to `init` as `&word` because it's wrong too!!

Answer (score 3):

Strings are not assignable in C.

You need to use `strcpy()` or `memcpy()` to copy the string

```
strcpy(word,randWord);
```

Comment: Of course!
Can't say I am very fond of C. Thank you for answering my nooby question.

Comment: Also, consider changing `char* randWord;` to `char* randWord = NULL;`

Comment: @abndonurfriends: If you're not very fond of C, and C++ is an option (you did tag it C++ after all), then pick up a beginners C++ book. With `std::string` you can in fact do `word = randword` and it just works..

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention to compiler warnings.

```
word.c: At top level:
word.c:16:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘init’
 void init(char* word)
      ^
word.c:8:4: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘init’ was here
    init(&word);
```

You pass pointer to pointer to init().

And yeah, as @Gopi said, you can't copy strings by assigning.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two different ways to fix this:

1. pass `init(word)`, and down in `init` say `strcpy(word, randWord)`.
2. Change `word` to `const char *word`, continue to call `init(&word)`, change the definition of `init` to `void init(const char ** word)`, and leave the assignment `*word = randWord`.  (In this case you should declare `words[]` and `randWord` as `const char *`, also.)